# sql query not working for three tables join

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, codeigniter

I applied the join query, but it seems to be not working. It's not selecting any data. When print_r the row_data is empty, but when I print_r $q it shows all the data,

```
public function getUserdata($id) {
    $id=$id;

    $query=$this->db->select('post_status.status_image')
        ->where('user_data.id',$id) 
        ->from('user')
        ->join('user_data', 'user.id = user_data.id')
        ->join('post_status', 'user.id = post_status.user_id')
        ->get();

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($query);

    exit();

    $q= $query->result_array(); 
    return $q;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use where after join like this

```
$query=$this->db->select('post_status.status_image')
->from('user')
->join('user_data', 'user.id = user_data.id')
->join('post_status', 'user.id = post_status.user_id')
->where('user_data.id',$id) 
->get();
```

also you can use `toSql()` instead of `get()` to check your raw query in phpMyAdmin. ;)